# ERROR PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/task/main.py'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a python Lambda that returns this error. This function only read a json event and parse some fields. Stop. I can't paste here the lambda code. This lambda has always worked and with no changes stopped!!!

Lambda code is taken from a BitBucket repository.

[image]

Comment: You will need to include a bit more detail.   Please include the full traceback error.

Answer (score 2):

Have you by any chance updated the .zip package for lambda? The error might have something to do with the following:

> The zip archive preserves file permissions, so if you have a 644
> permissions file, deflate it and inflate it back up, you get 644
> permissions for that file.

Try setting the expected permissions before deflation, in Lambda's case, 755 should do just fine.

Or... that JSON file the lambda reads might actually be in a folder and you're trying to read it.

Error 13 usually means *you are trying to open a file, but your path is a folder.*

Another possible reason for this might be the permission issues on the Lambda handler file.

Try this:

```sh
chmod 644 your_lambda_handler_file.py
```

And in the directory where your lambda code is, try this:

```sh
chmod 644 $(find . -type f)
chmod 755 $(find . -type d)
```

Comment: Thank you! Lambda code is taken from a BitBucket repository and all files permissions have been modified with 755 :(

Comment: Can you check CloudWatch Logs for possibly more error messages?

Comment: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 982, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1039, in get_data

Comment: Well, looks like you'll have to do some debugging at the repo level. Also, try to find the last successful invocation and compare what's changed.

Comment: all my file have all permissions :(

Comment: If it had worked before but now it doesn't then *something* must have changed. Good luck debugging!